# SOLR - Limiting Search Results

Tags: solr

Is there a way to restrict the number of search results returned from SOLR. I am working for a client who would like to restrict the search results to 100 (based on search score) . I can use rows but that would only restrict the results per page and not the total results. The problem with that is If the sort function of SOLR is used,  it would sort all the results and the product which has 105th rank based on score might come on top because of the low price. I want the sort to happen only on the top 100 results. Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks for your help!

Supreet

Comment: You mean you need to first fetch 100 rows and then sort the 100 rows?

Comment: yes. fetch first 100 rows and then sort them based on price or name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sort By Function](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function).

You will have to query the normal way with `rows=100` and also add the `&sort=<query>`.

I could not try it as I do not have a Solr instance right now. Please let me know if ti works or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried that. It gives the 100 lowest priced products from the result and not the top 100 (based on search score) relevant products sorted ( or orderd) by price. For e.g. if SOLR returns 700 results for a query then rows=100 and sort=price asc will return the 100 products out of those 700 with lowest price. What I am looking for is if we can restrict SOLR to generate only 100 results or if that is not possible then get 100 results using rows=100 and perform sorting on those 100 results. I have also tried sort=score desc,price asc but that also doesn't help.