# Restrict SOLR Search to First N Numbers

Tags: solr, solrj

Duplicate question for [SOLR-Limiting Seach results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164260/solr-limiting-search-results)

Is there any way where we can Override /customize SOLR search to return the fixed N number of results?.

Any pointer on how to achieve this?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the number of rows that are to be returned in the `solrconfig.xml` file.

Under the `requestHandler` tag you can have a list of defaults in which you can modify the `rows` that are to be returned by default. By default, the value is set to 10.

```
    <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>
```

Comment: You can also do this while querying by adding `&rows=N` in your query parameters

Comment: @AllanMacmillan - Yes that is right. The other question mentioned in the OP's question has that answer.

Comment: We have facets also so what your suggestion will do is will provide me N rows results along with facets for actual total Number Of Results. I wants top N results and Facets for Top N resultSet Only.Any Suggestion on how can achieve this through code change?